# How to access EC2 instance via SSH on mac with Operation Timed Out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect to an EC2 machine with the following command line on my terminal:

`ssh -i id_rsa_aws <ec2_ip_address> -l ec2-user -vvv`

Here is the result:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <ec2_ip_address> is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to <ec2_ip_address> [<ec2_ip_address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa_aws type 0
debug1: identity file id_rsa_aws-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

My ssh_config file:

```
Host *
        SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

I know the problem must come from my computer. I have tried using the .pem file and I am getting the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to SSH into any other EC2 instance in the same subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)